# Wifi connects, but no internet. Suspect IP issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a couple access points on my home network, and they used to work well, but recently I've noticed that quite often when I connect to the network the wifi connects, but there is no internet available. I've tracked the problem down to an IP issue, but I don't know hot to fix it.

### The set up:

My network is set up with very basic hardware, and almost no customization. The service comes through a fiber optic cable. The fiber optic cable connects to an ONT. This has been provided by my ISP. The brand name on the label is Optictimes, and the model is RX8102W.( [See product here](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Optical-Network-Terminal-Onu-Optictimes-RX8102W_1600290296391.html) ) This device has wifi capabilities, and some devices connect to it directly.

From the ONT I have two Ethernet lines. One is for an AP: a steren com-818 ([like this one](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1232005/Steren-Com-818.html)), and the other one is for a switch ([like this one](https://www.steren.com.mx/switch-fast-ethernet-de-8-puertos.html)).

From the switch I have 2 more AP connected. One is similar to the one I mentioned previously, and the other is a TPLINK ([like this one](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/access-point/tl-wa901n/)).

### The configuration:

- **ONT**: I have no access to it's config page. I know nothing about how
  it is configured. My ISP refuses to give up control over the ONT.
- **First COM-818**: Configured as an Access Point with a different SSID
  than the ONT.
- **Second COM-818**: Configured as an Access Point with a
  different SSID than the ONT, and the first COM-818.
- **TPLINK**:
  Configured as an Access Point with a different SSID than the ONT, and
  the two COM-818.

### My findings:

I found that whenever a device is connected to the network via wifi, but has no internet access, its assigned IP is in the 192.168.10.* range. 192.168.10.1 is the set up page for the com-818 Access Points accessible when you are connected to one of them. It appears to me that for some reason devices end up connected to the second COM-818 and assigned an IP in the 192.168.10.* range. This happens even when I choose to connect to the SSID for the ONT, or the TPLINK AP. The device shows that it is connected to that SSID, but it offers the config page for the COM-818 as if it were in fact connected to the COM-818, but not configured.

Disconnecting, and re-connecting fixes the problem. Sometimes on the first try, but sometimes it takes a few tries to work.

### Edit 1:

The output of ip addr when the connection is successfully made

```
wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:d8:19:8b:37:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp7s0
    inet 192.168.1.4/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9bf1:abab:4440:a7c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: You may have a 2nd DHCP server running on one of these devices. When a device requests an IP address and they race to provide it. If ISP's device wins, all is good. If the 2nd DHCP server is first, you get the wrong IP.

Comment: Do you want each AP to be a separate network, or should devices be able to talk to each other? How is each AP connected to the ONT (via a WAN or LAN port)? If you have more than one AP handing out IP addresses (dhcp), then your clients will get one at random in certain configurations. It looks like the COM APs should be in WDS (bridge) mode when configured in a chain like this: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2213933/Steren-Com-817.html?page=74

Comment: Thanks for the comments here. I've found no DHCP settings on the COM APs, and the TPLINK has it disabled. As for networks being separate, that is the end goal, but I do not have the hardware necessary to create separate VLans, so for now it is OK if they are on the same LAN.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale the manual page you linked is for a different device (COM-817)

Comment: @Buzu For **separate** networks, you'll want to 1) make sure each AP is using its WAN port to connect to the next device's LAN port, 2) run in full AP mode with dhcp enabled. For a **single** network, the ports shouldn't matter, bridge mode, and DHCP should *only* be running on the ONT. (I could only find the spanish version of the 818 manual, but I'd assume the models are not that different)

Comment: @Cpt.Whale they are actually quite different. The COM-818 is really basic. Here is the EN manual https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1232005/Steren-Com-818.html?page=36#manual

I think the problem does come down to what port I'm using to connect the COM-818. I tested the one that does not misbehave and got it to misbehave. What I did is I changed the port I'm using to connect it from WAN/LAN to the LAN port, and I started seeing the same behavior. I don't have access to the other COM-818 right now, but I'll check it later today and see what port is is using.

Comment: Use Wireshark to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. The comments I received were key to finding the solution. Now, if someone could explain the reason that would be so AWESOME.

The solution was to make sure both COM-818 were using the WAN/LAN port. The one that was causing trouble was actually using the LAN port.

I noticed a few oddities:

1. `nmap`ping the network would not report the problematic AP.
2. Switching ports on the COM-818 that was working well would leave it unable to access the internet even if the connection was made correctly, and the device would get an IP in the 192.168.1.* range. I would have to unplug it and plug it again to have it working well.
3. Connecting to the SSID of the problematic COM-818 would fail less often than connecting to the SSID of any of the other APs, including the ONT's.

I'm not sure WHY this happens. But the solution is quite simple: Use the correct port.

Bonus: I discovered that the COM-818 can be set up as routers, in which case they create a completely separate network. It is not a VLAN, but a separate network, I think.

Comment: Basic explanation: Clients broadcast their IP request to the entire local network, so anything on the same LAN is able to respond. Most router-type devices have a boundary between their LAN/WAN ports, which can stop clients from getting the wrong IP assignments. Turning on/off that barrier and dhcp also determines whether the clients on each AP can talk to each other

Comment: Yes, that sounds like that's what was happening. Thanks.